# cannot `lossage-size` a large number

Tags: error, crash

emacs-28.2; win 11

```
$ emacs -Q
```

1. If I use `most-positive-fixnum`:

   ```lisp
   (lossage-size most-positive-fixnum)
   ```

   Emacs will emit: `Value must be >= 100` in the *echo area*.
2. If I use a modest number:

   ```lisp
   (lossage-size (/ most-positive-fixnum 10))
   ```

   Emacs will crash immediately.

I just want to use `most-positive-fixnum` to indicate that I won't limit the size of lossage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If Emacs *crashes* then there's a bug in Emacs (in its C code). Do `M-x report-emacs-bug` immediately, in particular providing a recipe that starts with `emacs -Q` (no init file).
2. I tried `emacs -Q` followed by `(lossage-size (/ most-positive-fixnum 10))` in Emacs 28.2 on MS Windows, and it didn't crash.  It simply returned this value: 858993459.
3. Raising an error for `(lossage-size most-positive-fixnum)` seems like a bug, to me. Certainly the value of `most-positive-fixnum` is at least 100. *You might want to report this.*

---

You apparently reported this as Emacs bug#[62277](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62277), and as a result it's now been fixed for the upcoming Emacs 29 release.  ***Thanks!***

Comment: Did you watch the memory usage ?  The memory of my Emacs increased fast when eval `(lossage-size (/ most-positive-fixnum 10))`.

Comment: That's *not a crash*. And after it returned - or even if you used `C-g` to interrupt its evaluation - did you try evaluating it again?

Comment: No, I cannot try again during the same session because my Emacs just crashed, then a window (here window is a window in MS-Windows) popped up (asking me whether to debug emacs.exe).  I don't why the memory usage will increase.

Comment: Report the problem you see: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, whether it's actually a crash or something different.